# Crystal report validate database credentials before viewing report

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, crystal-reports

How to ask for database credentials from the user, before he/she can view a Crystal Report?

Does a new dialog need to be created with textbox controls of database login and password?

Or is there some feature in CR inbuilt for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about how to do it outside of Crystal Reports, you need to create your own custom prompt for the reports. The default viewer will not do it automatically.

One full-featured commercial product that does this is Report Runner (http://www.reportrunner.com).

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, It should be proceed in following ways

1. Open a ShowDialog Form and ask the user to validate the database credentials. Upon successful validation, preceed with showing the report, otherwise show some user friendly message.
2. While connecting to database, in case by mistake we enter the wrong username and password, then a dialog box pops up automatically ask for username and password to see the crystal reports. This can be intentional as well to open the Pop UP

The second point happened was in my past experience